# Using jsreport without studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, export-to-pdf, jsreport

I'm trying to use jsreport in an ASP.NET Core 1.1 website. Now, the setup that i have is very simple, like so: I edit the reports in cshtml Razor views (within Visual Studio, not jsreport's studio) and use ASP.NET Core's NodeServices to render the view into PDF format. This works wonderfully well (I'm not using the .NET sdk with all the middleware stuff, btw).
But, now I need to add headers and footers to my reports and I don't really know how to do that. I know it's possible using jsreport studio, but what if I don't use it for my reports? Is there some declarative way to embed headers and footers in a report? If not, how can I accomplish this otherwise? Maybe fiddle with files in the file system? Or some other way?

Thanks,
ashilon

Answer (score 1):

I would anyway recommend to boot up jsreport, open studio, define the header in ui, test the template and see how the request looks like in the F12 browser tools. Then you can do the same request in your node services.

It could be something like:

```
jsreport.render({
  template: {
    content: "foooo",
    recipe: "chrome-pdf",
    engine: "none",
    chrome: {
      marginTop: "3cm",
      displayHeaderFooter: true,
      headerTemplate: `<div style='font-size: 20px'>Hello header</div`
    } 
  }
}
```

https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf#native-headers-and-footers